# Infer return type of function from passed array of strings

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to infer the return type of a function in typescript from a passed array of strings?

```
type Options = {
    keywords?: string[];
};

function someFunction(options: Options): {[key: string]: string} {...}

let options: Options = { keywords: ['a', 'b']};
let result = someFunction(options);

// result = {
//    a: 'something',
//    b: 'something else'
// }

// result.a exists
// result.b exists
// result.c does not exist = error
```

At the moment, I am typing the function's return type as a loose dictionary, but would like to infer what keys are actually available depending the options input.

I had a play with `keyof`, `typeof` and `as const` but cannot seem to find the winning combination. Is it actually possible to type this?

Comment: `ReturnType<typeof someFunction>`

Comment: what definition has someFunction in terms of types and body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a type parameter to capture the `keyowrds` literal types. You can then use `Record` to create a type with those properties and of a specific type:

```
let result = someFunction({ keywords: ['a', 'b'] });
var o = { keywords: ['a', 'b'] } as const; //needed to preserve literal types if options are declared separately 
let result2 = someFunction(o);


function someFunction<V extends PropertyKey>(p: { readonly keywords: readonly V[] }) : Record<V, string>{
  return null!;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/FAGwpgLgBATmDOBXE0C8V4HsC2YBiiAdgMYQCWmhAFAN5QDWYAngO6YwAm8AXFANoByAIYCANFAEAjAQF0oAXwCUAbmAA3ITCiYo6Oo1bsuvQSPFTZCqEPhRileBFXhocJCgBMujDnxFSFNSYKsChAGb+5JQ+uAQkUYQAPABqUGAAHhBghFxQAAowmAAOYDAQTADSzAB8VEW8dHBCHJQgTAzMbJw8sGDNre3JfHJKULwASmD2nCnijjBkhADm1TTAUL0QiDCEUITIIACEqvLAQA)